# Is it possible to list all photo albums and get its Identifier in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios8

As the title suggest, is it possible, in Objective-C, to list all Photo albums and get its identifier?

I need to check if an album exists and corresponds to a specific identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `PHCollectionList` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHCollectionList_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/PHCollectionList). This will give you a list of all of the photo albums.

Comment: Thanks, i am using this library but my question is more "Is it possible to get the album identifier?"

Comment: A `PHCollection` and it's subclasses are all derived from `PHObject` which contains a `localIdentifier`. You would need to loop through your list of collections and get their `localIdentifier`s.